# Prove that for each $n$, there exist $n$ consecutive integers, each of which is divisible by a perfect square larger than $1$.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for each $n$, there exist $n$ consecutive integers, each of which is divisible by a
perfect square larger than $1$. Can any one help with this? I was stuck because I know how to solve for a particular $n$ value, but I was helpless in the generalized form.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) on the congruences:

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{2^2} \\ x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3^2} \\ x+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5^2} \\  \dots$$